# No method error undefined method `find' for #<TopFood:0x007fdfd5e0f4e0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, nomethoderror

I'am getting error

> ```
> NoMethodError in Data#input
>
> Showing /home/adijanuarsyah/Projects/Food/app/views/data/_idfood.html.erb
> ```
>
> where line #8 raised:
>
> ```
> undefined method `find' for #<TopFood:0x007fdfd558fa90>
> ```

When i'am used find method for getting query food = foods.find(rand_number) i'am getting error like above , but when using TopFood.find(rand_number), its working perfectly.

Here is my view

```
<h2>Suggestion Indonesian top dishes</h2>
<ul id="foodList">

        <% TopFood.where(:country => "ind").find_each do |foods |  %> 
        <% rand_number = rand(52) + 1 %> 
            <% @food = foods.find(rand_number)%>
                <li><%= @food.name  %></li> 
            <% puts @food.inspect %> 
    <% end %>

</ul>
<div id="loadMore">More sugesstions</div>
<div id="showLess">Show less</div>
```

Any clue as to what is going on here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find` is a class method, which cannot be called on an instance like `foods`.

To fix your code you can do:

```
<% TopFood.where(:country => 'ind', :id => rand(52) + 1).find_each do |food| %> 
  <li><%= food.name %></li> 
  <% puts food.inspect %> 
<% end %>
```

If you want to show results in a random order you can do this:

If your database is MySQL:

```
<% TopFood.where(:country => 'ind').order('RAND()').find_each do |food| %>
```

If your database is PostgreSQL or SQLite:

```
<% TopFood.where(:country => 'ind').order('RANDOM()').find_each do |food| %>
```

Comment: ohh, i see,  need more learning again about class and instance, now i get result, but just one food name result, how if i want find_each method get all my foods name?

Comment: `find_each` only returns one row, besides you're adding a random `id` and that will also only match one row. What are you trying to do exactly? If you want to display more than 1 food, just get rid of `, :id => rand(52) + 1`.

Comment: I'am trying to get all food name rows with contains country fields  "ind" , but with :id random , so the food name show dynamic every user loadd the page,if iam used @food = TopFood.find_by_id(rand_number) it can show all random food name, but not spesific by :country => 'ind'

Comment: Yes, exactly what i want, now i'am understand, if we want to get random :id just using order method, thank you for your help @Mischa